# What Unicode symbols are accepted in Python 3 variable names?

Tags: python, variables, unicode, syntax, python-3.x

I want to use a larger variety of Unicode symbols for variable names in my Python 3 scripts. What characters are acceptable to use in Python 3 variable names?

I recently started using Unicode symbols (such as Greek and Asian symbols) for code obfuscation.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why? Is 元亀 better than genki as an variable name?

Comment: I could then have a variable that sticks out more than the rest. For instance, variables for security purposes can be named using Greek characters, Japanese symbols for handling integers, etc.

Comment: I could then easily distinguish variables.

Comment: That sounds like something you should cover with naming conventions, unless you can guarantee you'll never have a maintainer or contributer who doesn't understand one of the languages you use.

Comment: I know that using odd symbols is not customary, but if we keep programming traditionally, then we keep get traditional programs. We need to think outside-of-the-box.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson There are other ways to break traditions which don't affect readability.

Comment: I tried some Chinese characters, they can begin variable names :)

Comment: @FredrikPihl , I recently started using Unicode symbols for code obfuscation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [PEP 3131](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/), the first character of an identifier needs to belong to `ID_Start`, the rest to `ID_Continue`, defined as follows:

> `ID_Start` is defined as all characters having one of the general
>   categories uppercase letters (Lu), lowercase letters (Ll), titlecase
>   letters (Lt), modifier letters (Lm), other letters (Lo), letter
>   numbers (Nl), the underscore, and characters carrying the
>   Other_ID_Start property. XID_Start then closes this set under
>   normalization, by removing all characters whose NFKC normalization is
>   not of the form `ID_Start ID_Continue*` anymore.
>
> `ID_Continue` is defined as all characters in `ID_Start`, plus
>   nonspacing marks (Mn), spacing combining marks (Mc), decimal number
>   (Nd), connector punctuations (Pc), and characters carryig the
>   Other_ID_Continue property. Again, `XID_Continue` closes this set
>   under NFKC-normalization; it also adds `U+00B7` to support Catalan.

That's a long list (currently around 120.000 characters) - fortunately [there is a helpful project on GitHub that contains the list and a script to generate it](https://github.com/microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/1208).

Comment: Where can I find the list of symbols that match \w?

Comment: But what Unicode symbols does Python3 accept as variable names? Can I use any Unicode symbol?

Comment: PEP 3131 refers to this table: http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html

Comment: Why are useful characters, like  (watermelon), not included?

Comment: It is really frustrating, that we can use glagolitic characters or viking runes to start our variable names, yet we cannot use pretty common symbols that you can type on most mobile devices and input on most computers. I get that we shouldn't start the variable names with numbers or math symbols with special meaning, but I think emojis would make damn good variable names in plenty of cases.

Comment: I'm trying to use nabla and partial in my physics calculation to no prevail. I thought the PEP3131 would support all unicode as long as they are not in spacing marks and combining marks etc.

Comment: It looks like [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) 1.7.2 still doesn’t support the full list of identifiers: `Invalid constant name "_黄" (invalid-name)`

Comment: I agree with grepe - apparently, we can't even pt those common symbols into variable names. I want to use a % symbol when I create a variable to hold percentages, for example!

Comment: @VickiB: That's impossible because `%` is the modulo operator and thus can't be part of a variable name, just like you can't use `+` or `-`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah, thanks for correcting me. It was an old runtime on a remote. My bad, too tired I guess.