# What Unicode symbols are acceptable in BASH variable names?

Tags: bash, variables, unicode, csh, tcsh

What [Unicode symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols) are acceptable in BASH variable names? Does the same list of symbols apply to CSH and TCSH?

Comment: I would like something like this dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html if possible.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043894/what-unicode-symbols-are-accepted-in-python3-variable-names.

Comment: I know that using odd symbols is not customary, but if we keep programming traditionally, then we keep get traditional programs. We need to think outside-of-the-box.

Comment: I'm unable to find a definitive reference, but I suspect identifiers are limited to ASCII alphanumeric characters and the underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say none.

```
á=3
á=3: command not found
```

If you like unicode symbol names, use Perl:

```
perl -e 'use utf8; $á = 42; print $á'
42
```

Comment: @l0b0: Want to nitpick? Devyn asked for [Unicode symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols), not characters.

Comment: +1 My bad - Clarified OP. I can honestly say I'd never heard of "Unicode symbols" as a *proper subset* of Unicode.