# Dash in dictionary key and eval

Tags: python

Before I get beat to death by the 'eval is evil' crowd, it's a necessary evil in this case and I can't change it.  Eval has it's uses, and in a tightly controlled environment it's very powerful.

However, I have an issue with no obvious solution and I'm hoping for outside the box thinking.

```
>>> mydict = {"a-b": "woohoo"}
>>> mydict["a-b"]
'woohoo'
>>> eval('mydict["a-b"]')
'woohoo'
>>> eval('a-b', mydict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Unfortuately, the last case is the one I'm forced to use and obviously it doesn't work.  Any ideas how to eval an expression into my 'globals' or 'locals' objects and not have it interpret the - as a minus operator?  Some of the keys in my 'globals' object do have dashes in the key names, and this is data I cannot control.

To the comments below.

- the data is coming to me from an external source.  I cannot dictate or control the format of the data at all.
- the 'clause' I'm evaluating is coming to me from user configuration that is stored.

This is part of a larger system, where users can push JSON data in via an api, we handle the data internally as a dictionary, then we apply certain rules to the data.  The rules are provided as configuration by the administrators from a web interface.

Ultimately, I need to allow the user to give me a (possibly complex) python one liner and evaluate it against a dictionary.  Isn't that exactly what `eval` is for? If there is a better way given I cannot dictating the format of the data and must allow the user to give me a *string* with an evaluation?  Eval is amazing because it lets the user do quite a few cool things, like use `.get()` and `len()`, but obviously it has downside as well like the aforementioned inability to distinguish or escape out the `-`.

Thanks!

Comment: We're going to need more context here. Why are you forced to use `eval`? Where are `mydict` and `"a-b"` coming from? Are you allowed to change the structure of `mydict`? What parts of this system are you allowed to change? `eval` is pretty clearly not suited for the task you want it to perform.

Comment: Are you aware that using `eval` like this mutates `mydict`, even if the expression you evaluate is non-mutative? It inserts a new `__builtins__` entry into `mydict`, which could be highly undesirable.

Comment: @user2357112 1) eval is all I can find that works 2) the data is coming from an uncontrolled external source 3) I cannot change the structure at all 4) I can write whatever code I like to accomplish the goals stated in my updated question.  And yes, I'm OK that eval mutates it, and that's fine in fact desirable as we want to allow as many python keywords in the evaluation as we can.  Thanks!

Comment: Since what you want to parse isn't Python, but a DSL with very similar syntax, why not just write yourself a parser which reads your new language and yields Python code you can then `eval`?  Tiresome, but perfectly doable.  (Sure, someone still will use your code just for evil, but to be fair they'd be teaching you an important lesson it sounds like you won't learn any other way. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to make the string "a-b" a symbol during your evaluation.  Traditionally, this doesn't work because "-" (hyphen) isn't *word*.  Only the [A-Za-z0-9_] (*word*) characters can be used in symbol names.  Changing hyphen to underscore works fine:

```
>>> mydict = {"a_b": "woohoo"}
>>> eval('a_b', mydict)
'woohoo'
>>>
```

However, in Python3, many Unicode characters can be used in a symbol and some might be adequate substitutions for ASCII hyphen:

```
>>> mydict = {"aᐨb": "woohoo"}
>>> eval('aᐨb', mydict)
'woohoo'
>>>
```

Here I used a Canadian syllabics final short horizontal stroke (though clearly an abuse of this code's intended purpose.)  See the posting [What Unicode symbols are accepted in Python3 variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043894/what-unicode-symbols-are-accepted-in-python3-variable-names) for more about this approach.

> I need to allow the user to give me a (possibly complex) python one
>   liner and evaluate it against a dictionary.

If that's the case, shouldn't `a` and `b` be part of that dictionary, which solves the problem:

```
>>> mydict = {"a": 34, "b": 13}
>>> eval('a-b', mydict)
21
```

Comment: I may not be being clear.  The actual key that comes in the document from the vendor is in the form "a-b", for example `{"item-count": 50}`.  So a practical example is `eval("item-count", mydict)` and I need it to return `50`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `mydict` as the global variable dict for the evaluated expression, give the user access to it as a dict:

```
eval(user_expression, {'data': mydict})
```

Then the user accesses it with expressions like

```
data['a-b']
```

instead of trying to use `a-b` as a variable name and needing to somehow break the Python parser. This is particularly nice if you might have a JSON array or other JSON type instead of a JSON object, since a Python list can't be used as the global variable environment for `eval`.

If you want to make the syntax a bit nicer, you can give the user Javascript-like dotted attribute access:

```
class ItemsAsAttributesDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

# when loading the JSON
dict = json.loads(json_string, object_hook=ItemsAsAttributesDict)
```

Then just like in Javascript, dict entries like `data['a']` can be accessed as `data.a`, but entries like `data['a-b']` still require bracket notation.

---

If you're set on using `mydict` as the global variables dict, the user will have to use `globals()` to access keys that aren't valid variable names:

```
globals()['a-b']
```

---

Be aware that using `eval` opens up nasty attack vectors. People are going to think these queries are safe, and they'll evaluate queries from untrusted sources, and then someone will ask for the value of

```
__import__('os').system('arbitrary_evil_command')
```

and everyone will hate you.

Also, using `eval` ties your program to Python syntax. You'll have a hell of a time porting it to any other language, especially since users will be depending on things like list comprehensions and other Python features you might not have expected them to use. You might even have a hard time transitioning between Python versions, or supporting different Python versions.