# Use Hyphen in key in Python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to use hyphen in key using python dict. But it is not working can anyone tell me how to fix this issue

```
dict1 = dict(with_underscore = "working")
print(dict1)
dict2 = dict(with-hyphen = "Not working")
print(dict2)
```

Error:

```
dict2 = dict(with-hyphen = "Not working")
                ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dash in dictionary key and eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734153/dash-in-dictionary-key-and-eval)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key with a hyphen is fine; that doesn't mean all key/value pairs can be represented by a keyword argument, since those are restricted to valid identifiers. You have to use one of the other forms, for example,

```
dict2a = dict([("with-hyphen", "Not working")])
dict2b = {"with-hyphen": "Not working"}
dict2c = dict(**{"with-hyphen": "Not working"})
```

(The last one is a little silly, but demonstrates that the key/value pairs of an existing dictionary can be passed without explicitly using keyword argument syntax.)

Comment: d1= dict(("with-hyphen", "Not working"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required

Comment: Oops, needs an iterable of tuples, not a single bare tuple. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem *is not* that keys can't have hyphens. Since they are just strings, they can. They problem is that the hyphen corresponds to the subtraction operator. So, python tries to evaluate the expression `with-hyphen`. That's a problem because the left of an assignment can't be an expression (for other reasons too).

Just use the regular `mydict = {'key-with-hyphen': 'value'}`

Comment: This works the way that you present it, but when I tried to build the same thing using the "dict(...)" syntax it was breaking no matter how I applied delimiters.  Perhaps there's another set of delimiters that works?  Thanks!

Comment: same issue. In the `dict(...)` syntax, the arguments on the left of `=` must be *valid python identifiers*. Since the hyphen is not part of a valid identifier, you can only use underscores.